# Vue dynamic load components and highlight code preview and preserve HTML structure

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, codemirror

Im trying to dynamic load vue components and when the component is visibile it should show the HTML of the component as a code preview.

This is successful and is working but is showing one big string because i use the $el.innnerHTML. What i want is that the structure of the component/html should be mirrored in the code preview.

**This is the result now:**

[image]

**What i want:**

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.14.0/themes/prism.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app" class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">

        <select v-model="selected" @change="onChange">
          <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
          <option value="componentOne">A</option>
          <option value="componentTwo">B</option>
        </select>

        <component :is="selected" :ref="mychildcomponent"></component>
        <code-highlight :code="codeHighlight"></code-highlight>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.14.0/prism.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    Vue.component("componentOne", {
      template: `
        <div>
          <div>
            <p>Home component</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        `
    });

    Vue.component("componentTwo", {
      template: `
        <div>
          <div>
            <p>Posts component</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      `
    });

    Vue.component("code-highlight", {
      props: ["code"],
      template: "<pre class='language-markup'><code class='language-markup' v-html='highlightedCode'></code></pre>",
      computed: {
        highlightedCode: function () {
          return Prism.highlight(this.code, Prism.languages.javascript);
        }
      },
    });

    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        selected: "",
        mychildcomponent: "mychildcomponent",
        codeHighlight: ""
      },
      methods: {
        onChange() {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.codeHighlight = this.$refs.mychildcomponent.$el.innerHTML;
          })
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Example**

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lukjuh/56af7kcb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<pre>` tag like:

```
Vue.component("componentOne", {
      template: `
        <pre>
          <div>
            <p>Home component</p>
          </div>
        </pre>
        `
    });
```

`<PRE>` tag will show text on web page as it is.